# Using gmock to mock a class which creates and instance of another class

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(struct param1, struct params2, struct param3)
        {
            inst1 = Create_B(param1);
            inst2 = Create_B(param2);
        }  

        int some_method(std::string st1, std::string st2, double d1, int s1);

   private:

        virtual classB* Create_B(struct param)
        {
            return new classB(param);
        }

    protected:
             classB *inst1;
             classB *inst2;
};
```

I would like to test Class A and mock out Class B. How would I go about doing this?

I have created a  Mock for Class A:

```
class MockA : public A
{
public:
    MockA(struct c1, struct c2, struct c3) : A(c1, c2, c3) {};
    virtual ~A() {}
    MOCK_METHOD1(Create_B, B*(struct));
};
```

But I am having trouble setting up my test. I am not sure how to setup my EXPECT_CALL and when I call some_method it should call a method with Class_B, can't figure out how to test for that.

```
TEST_F(Test_Fixture, VerifyA)
{
    /* Initialize */
    MockA  obj(param1, param2, param3);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two easy ways if you want to keep the code structure as is.

1. You could make the test class a friend of this class and then have the test class reset the class b member variables to be mocks
2. You can create a child class of this class in your test. Then have the child class set the parent class b member variables to be mocks

Comment: I have tried to do something similar as you mentioned in 2. But I am not sure how to setup my test. See code above.